# Telerik autocomplete - checking if user selected a value from the returned set of values

Tags: telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik autocomplete control on my mvc view. I want to show a message to user if the user selects/types a value which isn't from the list of values.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OnChange](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-combobox-client-api-and-events.html#OnChange) event which will be triggered when you blur from the AutoComplete. Also you have the new value under the **e.value** field of the event argument object.